# Add JS & CSS via observer to admin head in magento

Tags: javascript, css, xml, magento, observers

I need to add inline JS , JS paths & CSS  Paths/inline to the head of my magento admin based on settings form database, so only option I can think of is using an observer to load the js/css.

I have tried various techniques in the controller and xml level as below;

**Adminhtml Contoller**

```
//Does NOT append to head
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template','my.block', array('template' => 'my.file.phtml'));
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->append($block);
```

**XML Layout File**

```
<reference name="head">
<!-- Does NOT work -->
<block type="core/template" name="mytemplate" as="mytemplate" template="add.to.head.phtml"/>

<!-- Works but at End of page/footer, I need it in the head -->
<block type="core/template" output="toHtml" name="mytemplate" as="mytemplate" template="add.to.head.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

**Via Observer**

*config.xml*

```
<global>
...
<adminhtml_controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
        <observers>
            <add_stufftohead>
            <type>singleton</type>
                <class>myextension/adminobserver</class>
                <method>addJavascriptBlock</method>
            </add_stufftohead>
        </observers>
</adminhtml_controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
...
</global>
```

*Adminobserver.php*

```
//Does NOT work either
public function addJavascriptBlock($observer)
    {

    $js_core_output = "<![CDATA[<script type='text/javascript' >alert('Me works!!!!');</script>]]>";
    //Output to XML
    $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
    $update = $layout->getUpdate();
    $xml = "<reference name='head'><block type='core/text' name='add.to.head'><action method='setText'><text>
    $js_core_output
    </text></action></block></reference>";
    $update->addUpdate($xml);
    return;

   }
```

Seems it is difficult to add to magento admin head without using addCSS of addJS of overwriting head.phtml which I don't wont to do..